# Login user programmatically in magento not working properly?

Tags: php

Code which i am using is given below

```
public function loginUser($email, $password){
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    try {
        $log = $session->login($email, $password);
        return $log;
     } 

    catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

it returns 1 but not log in the browser , when i refresh the page it is not going set as a 
login user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need an additional call to `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::setCustomerAsLoggedIn()`

```
public function loginUser( $email, $password )
{
    /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
    $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );

    try
    {
        $session->login( $email, $password );
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn( $session->getCustomer() );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amit Maurya Was that a question?

Comment: this code is also work as above it return true but not login in to the browser

Comment: actually i want to login through designer tool software with php code

Comment: Well, it works from my TYPO3 plugin and connects both application logins…