# How to Create session for customer login with session outside magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am building a small web services code to where I need to have magento customer login. But not able to create the session. If I create the session from core/session it remains same for the browser for all the users.

Question 1:
Where are the sessions stored in the database?

Question 2: 
How to create customer/session and then to fetch that on different location with same session ID??

used this method but this is for core I need to know the customer is logged in or not with session id.:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"mobiledevice"));
```

This gives the browser session id not the customer

```
$session->getEncryptedSessionId()
```

Comment: Are you want to customer_id or customer session_id?

Comment: @Mufaddal Can we get both..

Comment: Better to ask at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are stored in database session table or something like that or, more commonly, in var/session. Depends on the install.

[Login user programmatically in magento not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912071/login-user-programmatically-in-magento-not-working-properly)

tells you how to log someone into magento "outside" of the magento. I do think the answer in the link is missing:

```
Mage::app('mysite');
```

before running the code. So something like this:

```
Mage::app('mysite');
$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
try
    {
        $session->login( $email, $password );
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn( $session->getCustomer() );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        //error handling code
    }
```

to create a user look here:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/

Comment: Sir Login Done But now couldn't check whether the user is logged in or not. as the customer session id on session.php file is something different

Comment: What about:
`Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()`

Comment: Sir I tried this:

$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session", array('name' => 'mobiledevice'));
$session->login($email, $password);
$custData = $session->getCustomer()->getData();
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
$session->start();

but I just saw my session is not created